# Swagger - Modified Theme not loading

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api2, swagger, swagger-ui, swashbuckle

I tried utilizing the modded Swagger UI from here

https://github.com/jensoleg/swagger-ui

I downloaded and used the `dist` folder but the UI is not loading at all.

I use Swashbuckle in my Web API project and it just loads properly.
Also the `dist` folder from the original Swagger UI project loads without any hassles.

Any one can offer insight into why there is an issue with
https://github.com/jensoleg/swagger-ui?

Answer (score 1):

Swashbuckle is by default using **embedded resources** for Swagger UI, which means the index page, its JS, CSS & images are taken **from the assembly itself**.

To customize it, you needs to override Swashbuckle behavior by [customizing its configuration API](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle#customizing-the-swagger-ui) to [use you new index page](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle#provide-your-own-index-file).

Your local resrouces (JS + CSS from the Github project) should then be working from your Web API project if access apaths are fine.